# Maximum Likelihood optimal threshold

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation, decision-theory

I have a decision (detection) problem trying to decide between symbols ${0,2}$. I have the two probability density functions: $$
f(z|s=0) =
\begin{cases}
0.25z + 0.5, & -2\le\ z <0 \\
-0.25z + 0.5, & 0\le\ z \le\ 2
\end{cases}
$$

and $$
f(z|s=2) =
\begin{cases}
0.25z, & 0\le\ z <2 \\
-0.25z + 1, & 2\le\ z \le\ 4
\end{cases}
$$

How can i mathematically prove that the optimal threshold value $T$ for that decision problem is equal to $1$?

Comment: Didier Piau has used the result that the maximum-likelihood decision rule minimizes the sum of the false-alarm and missed-detection probabilities.  If you were to _sketch_ the two densities, and remember that the _maximum-likelihood_ decision rule is that if the observation has value $\alpha$, then the decision is in favor of whichever hypothesis has larger _likelihood_ $f(\alpha\mid H_i)$, you will see immediately that the threshold is $T = 1$.  Decide $s = 0$ or $2$ according as the observed value $\alpha$ is smaller than or greater than $1$.  But I suppose that is not a mathematical proof.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: thank you, that is enough for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tries to maximize the probability $\frac12R(T)$ to guess right, where
$$
R(T)=\int_{-\infty}^Tf(z\mid s=0)\,\mathrm dz+\int_T^{+\infty}f(z\mid s=2)\,\mathrm dz.
$$
Thus, 
$$
R'(T)=f(T\mid s=0)-f(T\mid s=2).
$$
The function $R'$ is piecewise affine, $R'(T)=0$ if $T\lt-2$ or $T\gt4$, $R'(T)=\frac14T+\frac12$ if $-2\lt T\lt0$, $R'(T)=-\frac12T+\frac12$ if $0\lt T\lt2$, $R'(T)=\frac14T-1$ if $2\lt T\lt4$.

In particular, $R'(T)\gt0$ if $-2\lt T\lt1$ and $R'(T)\lt0$ if $1\lt T\lt4$. One sees that $R(T)$ is maximum at $T=1$.